# how to make currentPriceIndicator be visible as default in Highstocks?

Tags: highcharts

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/stock-tools-gui in the left menu there is a button to enable: "Current Price Indicator". How to make it visible by default?

I've tried series.lastPrice but it does not work in the same way as "Current Price Indicator".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve functionality like `Current Price Indicator` from stock tool GUI you need to[extend](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) core Highcharts code, that activate the current price indicator.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e4rz60nw/

Comment: is it not a bug that this requires to extend core Highcharts code? should it not be available in the Highcharts API?

Comment: There is no such function in the general stock options, you can from the fact that it is already in the GUI and so as not to load the core stock additionally. You can submit it as a feature request [GH](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose).